# GraphqlJS- Type conflict- Cannot use union or interface

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

```
const {
  makeExecutableSchema
} = require('graphql-tools');
const resolvers = require('./resolvers');

const typeDefs = `

  type Link {
    args: [Custom]
  }

  union Custom = One | Two

  type One {
    first: String
    second: String
  }

  type Two {
    first: String
    second: [String]

  }

  type Query {
    allLinks: [Link]!

  }

`;

const ResolverMap = {
  Query: {
    __resolveType(Object, info) {
      console.log(Object);
      if (Object.ofType === 'One') {
        return 'One'
      }

      if (Object.ofType === 'Two') {
        return 'Two'
      }
      return null;
    }
  },
};

// Generate the schema object from your types definition.
module.exports = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  ResolverMap
});


//~~~~~resolver.js
const links = [
    {
        "args": [
            {
                "first": "description",
                "second": "<p>Some description here</p>"
            },
            {
                "first": "category_id",
                "second": [
                    "2",
                    "3",
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
];
module.exports = {
    Query: {
        //set data to Query
        allLinks: () => links,
        },
};
```

I'm confused because the documentary of graphql is so bad. I don't know how to propertly set resolveMap function to be able to use union or interface in schema. For now when I'm using query execution it shows me error that my generated schema cannot use Interface or Union types for execution. How can I execute properly this schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resolvers` and `ResolverMap` should be defined together as `resolvers`. Also, type resolver should be defined for the `Custom` union type and not for `Query`.

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    //set data to Query
    allLinks: () => links,
  },
  Custom: {
    __resolveType(Object, info) {
      console.log(Object);
      if (Object.ofType === 'One') {
        return 'One'
      }

      if (Object.ofType === 'Two') {
        return 'Two'
      }
      return null;
    }
  },
};

// Generate the schema object from your types definition.
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});
```

**Update:**
OP was getting an error `"Abstract type Custom must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Link.args with value \"[object Object]\", received \"null\"."`. It’s because the conditions in type resolver `Object.ofType === 'One'` and `Object.ofType === 'Two'` are always false as there is no field called `ofType` inside `Object`. So the resolved type is always `null`.

To fix that, either add `ofType` field to each item in `args` array (`links` constant in `resolvers.js`) or change the conditions to something like `typeof Object.second === 'string'` and `Array.isArray(Object.second)`

Comment: Im getting now error:  `"Abstract type Custom must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Link.args with value \"[object Object]\", received \"null\"."` Must I define `type Custom`? What it should contain?

Comment: I think it’s because `Object.ofType === 'One'` and `Object.ofType === 'Two'` are always `false`. So the resolved type is always `null`. Try adding `ofType` field to each item in `args` array (`links` constant in `resolvers.js`). Or change the conditions to `typeof Object.second === 'string'` and `Array.isArray(Object.second)`. I can’t verify as I’m not at my computer now.

Comment: OH MY GOD, you, I love you. I have thinking about it for weeks, bunch of people tried to help me and after that long time, there is finally an aswer. You are my saviour. You don't know how thankfully I am now.